# Is there a way to specify a bin width for multi column sorting in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

This is my sort object:

```
{
  income: 1,
  age: 1
}
```

The problem is that `income` in theory is a real number, and hence unique. So this may render `age` to have no effect, unless `income` can be binned.

How to specify this in MongoDB aggregation? And would this binning operation, if possible, be too expensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved fairly easily with an aggregation stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: { roundedIncome: { $floor: "$income"}}},
  {$sort: {"roundedIncome": 1, "age": 1}}
])
```

You can of course change `$floor` to any expression you want for the resolution you want (e.g., 1dp, etc).

As you point out - there are performance considerations to this - the biggest one is if you hoped to use an index for the sort on `income` - this now won't be the case, which will cause an in-memory sort (with the limits that entails).

The cost otherwise will be equivalent to 1 `Math.floor` operation per document looked at. This could end up being the entire collection - since you can't skip/limit until you've sorted and you can't sort until you've ran the `$set`.

You could negate the cost to a certain extent by running the sort on `income` first, then the skip/limit, then the `$set` + `$sort` at the end - your results would be *slightly* inaccurate - but possibly acceptable